# Counting items in postgresql with outputting zero for those no found

Tags: postgresql

I make the following request to count my items:

```
    SELECT COUNT(cee."entryId"), cee."categoryId" FROM category_entries_entry cee
    WHERE cee."categoryId" IN (1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY cee."categoryId";
```

If items with ids 1 and 2 not found then I will only see the result for item with id = 3. Nevertheless I would like to get the following output:

```
count|categoryId|
-----|----------|
    1|         0|
    2|         0|
    3|         5|
```

How do I achieve it?

**Meta:**

PostgreSQL version: 12.3

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Aaah, yeaaah I know...I'm planning on solving this issue. I will look into it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join against a values clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(cee."entryId"), 
       t.id as category_id
FROM ( 
    values (1),(2),(3)
) as t(id) 
   left join category_entries_entry cee on cee."categoryId" = t.id
GROUP BY t.id;
```